# Myetherwallet Insufficient balance for transactionGas limit set dangerously high. Approving this transaction is likely to fail

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, cryptokitties

I'm trying to buy a cripto kittie that costs 0.0035 ETH which is around 3.14 dollars. I'm using my ether wallet for the transaction and when I set up the Gas Limit I get the following error on Metamask:

> Insufficient balance for transactionGas limit set dangerously high.
>   Approving this transaction is likely to fail.

I tried setting Gas Limit to 2100, 1, 2 ,3, 0.5 and I still get the same error.

[image]

I also don't understand where is the 303.04 dollars estimate coming from if the price of the Kittie is 0.0035 ETH. How to calculate Gas Limit I used ethgasstation.info and still I can get the Gas Limit to get this transaction to pass.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your price per gas unit is set super high -- 41 Gwei, and the limit is 7,600,027 gas units. 41 * 7,600,027 = 311,601,107 Gwei, or 0.311601107 ETH (which estimates to about $300 USD right now).

You need to lower the price per gas unit and the gas limit. The error message basically says that the transaction will fail because you don't have enough money in the transaction to cover the theoretical max gas used (which is the approx 0.31 ETH figure).

Comment: I just got it to work by updating metamask but I thought just by adding the Gas Limit on the filed in myetherwallet as shown in the image abouve would transfer that to metamask. The information you provided was very helpful thank you

Comment: On the Metamask transaction confirmation screen, you can type in the text field that has the 7,600,027 figure. You can see this text field in your screenshot.

Comment: Even tho the transaction when thru when I check the tx I get the following error:  Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas] 
  https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc2b3772040881886487e85f4705711f7c7821020461537c7b330d8be8f6580fa   When I check in my kitties I still have no kitties. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Again your *gas price* is way too high. [This transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc9eb0467a7bbe15bbd1ef75c965d9faf84c424952b3ec09db2b85ce74077d4a6) executed with a gas price of 0.35 Gwei, and used 140895 gas. You need to lower the *gas price* and *raise the limit*.

Comment: what should I set the gas price to?

Comment: I put gas limit at 25000 and the gas price at .25 Gwei and the transaction fails, I get Error: nonce too low

Comment: The [website you linked to](https://ethgasstation.info/) has a suggested "Gas Price SafeLow," which you can use if you like. I prefer not to suggest what people should and shouldn't do when it comes to money, but 1 Gwei is certainly more reasonable than 34 Gwei (your transaction).

Comment: Please ask separate questions on the actual Q&A site rather than comments -- we can't really adequately help you in a hands on way.